# mvn exec:java - The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature

Tags: java, maven, maven-module, maven-exec-plugin

I have a maven project with one sub-module. If when I run `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=<name>` it give the error in title.
Project structure and poms are as follows:
file structure:

```
akka-topics-java
├── pom.xml
└── up-and-running
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
           main/java/....
```

parent pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- boilerplate for project and modelVersion -->

    <groupId>akka-topics-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <!-- Other stuff: <name>, some <properties>, <dependencies> and <dependencyManagement> -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- boilerplate for project and modelVersion -->

    <artifactId>up-and-running</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>akka-topics-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <name>Chapter 2: Up and Running</name>
</project>
```

The interesting part though, is when I change from `exec:java` to `exec:exec` and change the configuration a bit, it works.
If I change the plugin in parent pom like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-cp</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>${file}</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and execute `mvn compile exec:exec -Dfile=<name>` it works.
Note 1: I run all these commands after `cd up-and-running`.
Note 2: This is not really a java project.
It's full of java files that are independent and each have their `public static void main`.
Note 3: The full project is [here](https://github.com/ParSal123/akka-topics-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for maven-exec-plugin to "`exec:java` some class", the class needs to be *public*. I didn't specify any, so my class was *package private*.

Comment: So did it work from the command line then?

Comment: Yes. `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=<className>`. I don't know what the difference between `exec:java` and `exec:exec` is, But changing to `public` worked for `exec:java` and `exec:exec` didn't care about `public`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).